# googletest internal compilation error: too few template arguments with g++/clang/macos

Tags: c++, googletest

I recently installed gtest and tried to make a simple "helloworld" type of test. However I encountered compilation problems in gtest internal files when running g++:

```
g++ -std=c++11 tests.cpp -I /usr/local/include -lgtest -lpthread

In file included from tests.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h:60:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-death-test.h:43:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-death-test-internal.h:46:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h:48:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:114:
/usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:635:54: error: too few template arguments for class template 'less'
  typedef ::std::map<std::string, CodeLocation, std::less<>> RegisteredTestsMap;
                                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional/operations.h:473:29: note: template is declared here
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS less
                            ^
In file included from tests.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h:60:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-death-test.h:43:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-death-test-internal.h:46:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h:48:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:114:
/usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:612:22: error: member reference base type 'testing::internal::TypedTestSuitePState::RegisteredTestsMap' (aka 'int') is not a structure or union
    registered_tests_.insert(
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:618:29: error: member reference base type 'const testing::internal::TypedTestSuitePState::RegisteredTestsMap' (aka 'const int') is not a structure or union
    return registered_tests_.count(test_name) > 0;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:622:5: error: 'testing::internal::TypedTestSuitePState::RegisteredTestsMap' (aka 'int') is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
    RegisteredTestsMap::const_iterator it = registered_tests_.find(test_name);
    ^
/usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:622:62: error: member reference base type 'const testing::internal::TypedTestSuitePState::RegisteredTestsMap' (aka 'const int') is not a structure or union
    RegisteredTestsMap::const_iterator it = registered_tests_.find(test_name);
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
/usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:623:41: error: member reference base type 'const testing::internal::TypedTestSuitePState::RegisteredTestsMap' (aka 'const int') is not a structure or union
    GTEST_CHECK_(it != registered_tests_.end());
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1005:35: note: expanded from macro 'GTEST_CHECK_'
  if (::testing::internal::IsTrue(condition)) \
                                  ^~~~~~~~~
6 errors generated.
```

Code I used:
https://gist.github.com/mawenbao/9223908

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. Please read [ask] then provide [mcve]. You can [use this link](https://godbolt.org/z/Thahrxqc8) as starting point.

Comment: Which version of gcc do you have? Error is caused by missing feature from C++14. If you have old version of `gcc` then default version of C++ standard is lower then C++14. Add `-std=c++14` to `gcc` arguments.

Comment: @MarekR it was indeed -std=c++14 that I was missing, thank you

Comment: Even though the problem seems solved, please update the question with your code so it can be more helpful to future readers. I also took the liberty of slightly editing your question - PTAL

Answer (score 1):

@MarekR's answer was right, I was missing -std=c++14 in my g++ flags, before that I added -std=c++11 because of multiple warning that appeared, I did not anticipate to push the standard to even higher version.
Thanks